# Where do I place the pattern to allow dot in a regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm not the greatest when it comes to Regex. I found one that fullfills my requirements, but I also need it to allow dot (only one and in the end of a sentence).

The regex is this one: `/^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]+(\s*[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]*)*[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]+$/`

If possible, could someone send me the same regex, but with the mentioned conditions?

Regards,

Cristian.

Comment: Just add `\.` right before the `$`.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
/^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]+(\s*[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]*)*[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]+$/
```

To this to allow an optional dot at the end of the sentence:

```
/^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]+(\s*[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]*)*[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]+\.?$/
```

Explanation:
`\.?` is an escaped dot, the question mark makes it optional.

Comment: @Cristian Paolini: Does this answer address your needs? If so would you care to accept it? If not, add some more details to your question.